# How to put byte stream image data into JSON object?

Tags: java, json, image, arrays

I want to  put multiple images in JSON object using byte stream format, i wrote the following code.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(pathToImages+"//"+"01.jpg");

        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);  

        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);  
        int ch =0; ;  

        sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder= new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
        byte[] contents = new byte[5000000];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        String strFileContents;
        while ((bytesRead = bin.read(contents)) != -1) {
            bout.write(encoder.encode(contents).getBytes());
        }
JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();
```

I want to put encoded byte stream in myObj,but dont know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: if you are on Java 8, you may want to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject();
myObj.put("1",encoder.encode(contents).getBytes());
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Java 8, and the [javax.json](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html) package:

```
Path path = Paths.get(pathToImages, "01.jpg");

ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
    (int) (Files.size(path) * 4 / 3 + 4));

try (OutputStream base64Stream = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(bytes)) {
    Files.copy(path, base64Stream);
}

String base64 = bytes.toString("US-ASCII");

JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
builder.add("data", base64);

JsonObject myObj = builder.build();
```