# String image base64 avoid other data include in JSON object (android java)

Tags: android, json, base64

I convert bitmap to string base64. Then put it in json object. But the next data after the string base64 not include and not properly close the json. But when i put comment code for the string base64, the data will include and close json properly.

This my code for android, convert signature bitmap to base64 string and put it in json object.

```
    Bitmap bitmapSignature = inkView.getBitmap(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));


    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapSignature.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

    String signature = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    LogCustom.i(signature, "signatureOutput");
```

This my code for JSON Object

```
JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject();

        JSONArray jobUpdatesArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jobUpdatesObject = new JSONObject();
        jobUpdatesObject.put("Name", "John");
        jobUpdatesObject.put("Signature", signature);
        jobUpdatesObject.put("Address", "London");
        jobUpdatesObject.put("Country", "England");
        jobUpdatesArray.put(jobUpdatesObject);
        rootObject.put("Job", jobUpdatesArray);
```

The output i got is like this. (signature long string, address and country not included and not close the json object)

```
{"Job": [{  "Name":"John","Signature": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABAQAAAINCAYAAACpuK0dAAAABHNCSQQSDFRVRTBx
```

It not close the json..But when i put comment code for signature. I got properly json.

```
{"Job": [{  "Name": "John","Address": "London", "Country": "England" }]}
```

How to put string base64 properly in JSON object ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574736/how-to-put-byte-stream-image-data-into-json-object 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767615/how-to-display-image-byte-array-from-json-into-imageview-factory-returns-nu

Check This Out... Hope This Helps

Comment: i already see but it convert to byte not to string

Comment: This Code is working Fine.... I just Checked Your's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void getByteArray(){
        Bitmap bitmapSignature = ((BitmapDrawable)YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); // I changed this to get bitmap from ImageView rest Same

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmapSignature.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

        String signature = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.i(signature, "signatureOutput");

        JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject();

        JSONArray jobUpdatesArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jobUpdatesObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jobUpdatesObject.put("Name", "John");
            jobUpdatesObject.put("Signature", signature);
            jobUpdatesObject.put("Address", "London");
            jobUpdatesObject.put("Country", "England");
            jobUpdatesArray.put(jobUpdatesObject);
            rootObject.put("Job", jobUpdatesArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i(rootObject.toString(), "signatureJSON");
    }
```

Log Value :

```
{"Job":[{"Name":"John","Signature":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB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\n","Address":"London","Country":"England"}]}
```

Logger Class

```
 public static class Log {

    public static void d(String TAG, String message) {
        int maxLogSize = 20000;
        for(int i = 0; i <= message.length() / maxLogSize; i++) {
            int start = i * maxLogSize;
            int end = (i+1) * maxLogSize;
            end = end > message.length() ? message.length() : end;
            android.util.Log.d(TAG, message.substring(start, end));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: for this code YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); .. I need to change with ?

Comment: bitmapSignature = inkView.getBitmap(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)); .. right ? i don't know why for me the string of base64 so long

Comment: Yes You have To Change with yours YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Comment: You try get high quality of image and try again ? i don't know why for me still not worked..The string of base64 still long

Comment: K I'll try with high resolution image

Comment: Thanks Sir, but i really don't know why for me it not worked

Comment: @user7345006 Your Code working..... The only Problem is default Log Not Showing Full Output.... If You Wanna See Complete Log Use the Log I Updated In My Answer To See.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142272/discussion-between-maharith-aditya-s-s-and-user7345006).

Comment: Sir.. i already add that class but the result still same .. still not show data after signature string base64

Comment: Change maxLogSize and Check buddy

Comment: i already change to 100000 but still not show data after signature.

Comment: Buddy i checked 1600 * 900 it worked with 20000.... What's the image resolution....

Comment: actually i got image from signature using this library https://github.com/simplifycom/ink-android .. Can u try this library , this is easy to setup.

Comment: @user7345006 Can I ask you one thing. Why are you so keen about Log. Your JSON is Working Right. If you Send to your server it will work. Then Why you bother about log so much.

Comment: :-) actually i got error from server so i feel not satisfied if cant see all the log and i not control the api to see exact data. But its okay, i just leave this log part. Thanks so much Sir

Comment: I'll try today and let you know of it

Comment: Sir .. already worked.. Yes my code no error .. just error at server side .. Thanks a lot sir